# Trying to bring the properties/values such as the names or dates of an XML file into java from a directory

Tags: java, xml

Trying to bring the properties/values such as the names or dates of an XML file into java from a directory. but the problem is i can only bring in the names of the files such as Employee or Dates but cannot bring in the elements inside the file

```
  public class ProcessXML {
      public static void main2(String[] args) {

      File f = null;
      File[] paths;

      try{      
         // file
         f = new File("/Users/Adrian/Dropbox/XML.xml");

         // array of files and directory
         paths = f.listFiles();

         // for each name in the path array
         for(File path:paths)
         {
             path.isDirectory();
            // prints filename and directory name
            System.out.println(path);
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
         // if any error occurs
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

          File f = null;
          try{      
             // file
             f = new File("Users/Adrian/Dropbox/XML.xml");
             //other file
            //f = new File("/Users/Adrian/Dropbox/");
             listFile(f, "    ");
          }catch(Exception e){
             // if any error occurs
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

    private static void listFile(final File file, final String indent) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
       if (file.isFile()) {
           if (file.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
               System.out.println(indent + "File " + file.getName());
      //                   final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
               processXML(file);
            }
       } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
           System.out.println(indent + "Dir " + file.getName());
           final File[] children = file.listFiles();
           for (final File child : children) {
               listFile(child, indent + "    ");
           }
       }
     }

                                                                                                                                                                                       private static void processXML(final File file) throws 
       IOException,  ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
       Document doc = db.parse(file);


   }

}
```

Trying to bring the properties/values such as the names or dates of an XML file into java from a directory.the problem i am now having is trying to get the xml values out of the xml files i am nout sure what way to about it so if anyone has examples or can tell me which way to go about it it would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it can not find the file since you didn't include the extension to the xml file.
try add .xml to the end of the file path and see if that works

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Is this better explained? :)

Comment: No sorry the code actually already had the .xml at the end i just pasted in the wrong part of the code. i edited it there. but the problem is i can only bring in the names of the files such as Employee or Dates but cannot bring in the elements inside the file

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.io.File;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.Element;
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


 public class XPathTest {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {

 File Employee = new File("Employee.xml");
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = dBuilder.parse(Employee);
 doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

  System.out.println("root of xml file" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
  System.out.println("==========================");

   for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
   Node node = nodes.item(i);


      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Element element = (Element) node;
      System.out.println("Employee Age: " + getValue("age", element));
      System.out.println("Employee Name: " + getValue("name", element));
     System.out.println("Employee Gender: " + getValue("gender", element));
     System.out.println("Employee Role: " + getValue("role", element));
     } 
     }
     }          catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
       }
     }

     private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
     NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes(); 
     Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
     return node.getNodeValue();
    }
    }


    went onto change everything and now it works, brought in xml values without a problem
```